# How to open slimerjs without display?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, slimerjs

My environment:

> Ubuntu 16.04, slimerjs 1.0.0, firefox 58.0, root.

I'm trying to execute a js-scenario, but I got an error:

```
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified
```

Got the same error in *phantomjs*, and it was solved by:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
```

But on *slimerjs* it had no effect.

Comment: 'export DISPLAY=:0' should work I guess.

Comment: Tryed, got that:
`Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0`

Comment: Check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/871092/failed-to-connect-to-mir-failed-to-connect-to-server-socket-no-such-file-or-di

Comment: Solved by with adding `xvfb-run` prefix, example: `xvfb-run slimerjs ~/scripts/tennis.js`. Works fine.